# Arithmetic series, finding n

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: Find the sum of $$8 + 11 + 14 + ... + 602 + 605$$

I know the formula to find the first n terms of a series is given by $$ S_n = (\frac{a + a_n}{2})n $$

However, I don't know how to find how many terms are in this series. How do I find this out??

Comment: You count the terms!

Comment: $(605-8)/3+1$...

Answer (score 4):

The difference is $3$, so how many additions of $3$ to $8$ does it take to make $605?$  Generally, you have $a=8, a+nd=605$ and you know $d$, so solve the two equations.  Don't make a fencepost error in the number of terms.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a+(n-1)d=605??

Comment: @THELONEWOLF.:  that depends on whether you start counting at $0$ or $1$. OP has said the first term is $a$ and the last is $a_n$, so I took that to be $n+1$ terms and the last is $a+nd$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** How many terms are there in $4,6,8,10$? First term is $4$, last term is $10$ and the difference between two consecutive is $2$, so you can just calculate $(10-4)/2 + 1$. Try to do something similar in your case.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you know the formula, you just to need to calculate number of terms which can be given in an AP as $n=\frac{a_n-a}{d}+1$ where $a$ is first term, $a_n$ is last term and $d$ is common difference.

In your case you have $a=8,d=3,a_n=605$. Just take n from here and put in the formula which you alredy know.

I shall let you conclude now.